# How to modify a CSV file in Xcode Project Navigator

Tags: swift, xcode, csv

I'm currently working with a team that updates different rows and columns of a CSV file that lives locally in the app. The issue is that they have resorted to copying and pasting the entire CSV file into a new CSV file, modifying data and copying the edited CSV file and pasting it back into the project. I was curious if anyone had any suggestions on how they can edit the CSV file in Xcode without the complicated mess of copying and pasting.

P.S. `Quick Look` would prove useful if you could edit the CSV file in this mode.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach could be to have a reference to the file instead of a hard copy, this way each time you edit the file it should update on the project automatically. Look at this link for more refs: http://www.thomashanning.com/xcode-groups-folder-references/

Answer (score -1):

**This answer will only work if you have software such as Microsoft Excel on your computer.**

In the `Project Navigator`, right click the `csv` file and select `open with external editor`. This will allow for Xcode to open the `csv` file using Excel. Modify any data as needed and save your work on Excel. Your `csv` file in Xcode will now reflect your changes made in Excel.